# Importing Scriptblock from file

Tags: powershell, winrm

I've got a working Powershell script and I'd like to have the scriptblock pulled in from an external file.

**Working:**

```
$scriptblock = { ... }
invoke-command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock -ArgumentList $server,$team -Credential $credential -asjob -JobName Dashboard_$server -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -NoMachineProfile)
```

Output of "get-job -id  | receive-job" is fine

**Not working:**

```
# Generate scriptblock from file
$file = Get-Content E:\Dashboard\Windows\winrm_scriptblock.txt
$Scriptblock = $executioncontext.invokecommand.NewScriptBlock($file)

invoke-command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock $Scriptblock -ArgumentList $server,$team -Credential $credential -asjob -JobName Dashboard_$server -SessionOption (New-PSSessionOption -NoMachineProfile)
```

Output of "get-job -id  | receive-job" is empty

The contents of winrm_scriptblock.txt is exactly what is included between the braces in the scriptblock variable defined in the working version.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Does this work for you? `$Scriptblock = [scriptblock]::Create((Get-Content E:\Dashboard\Windows\winrm_scriptblock.txt))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason not to just use the -FilePath parameter of Invoke-Command?

Comment: Taking me as an example - I would like to execute script block on remote machine, by passing it through arguments or with using variable scope, so this won't work for me.

Answer (score 14):

I know you already have answers, but another way to get a scriptblock from a script file is to use the `get-command` cmdlet:

```
$sb=get-command C:\temp\add-numbers.ps1 | select -ExpandProperty ScriptBlock
```

$sb is now the scriptblock for the script.

Comment: This worked to load a standalone ps1 containing CmdletBindings while the above answers failed.

Answer (score 4):

Very related to the answer from [How do I pass a scriptblock as one of the parameters in start-job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844390/how-do-i-pass-a-scriptblock-as-one-of-the-parameters-in-start-job)

If you stored the string "Get-ChildItem C:\temp" in the file "E:\Dashboard\Windows\winrm_scriptblock.txt" then this code should output the contents of the folder "C:\temp" on your local machine.

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create((Get-Content "E:\Dashboard\Windows\winrm_scriptblock.txt")))
```

**Parameters**

As far as passing parameters goes [Pass arguments to a scriptblock in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347214/pass-arguments-to-a-scriptblock-in-powershell) covers that answer as well. As [Keith Hill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153982/keith-hill) states: *a scriptblock is just an anonymous function*

Consider the following file contents

```
param(
    $number
)

$number..2 | ForEach-Object{
    Write-Host "$_ lines of code in the file."
}
```

And the command

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create((Get-Content "E:\Dashboard\Windows\winrm_scriptblock.txt"))) -ArgumentList "99"
```

Would give you the annoying output of

```
99 lines of code in the file.
98 lines of code in the file.
97 lines of code in the file.
....
```

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't work for me.   My scriptblock is around 350 lines long and accepts parameters.  Not sure if that matters.

Comment: I will try and pass it parameters and see if it works. The length itself should not matter at all

Comment: @kernelpanic The updated answer should cover that base.

Answer (score -3):

you must extract {} from E:\Dashboard\Windows\winrm_scriptblock.txt