# Powershell Start-job invoke function argument with parameter

Tags: function, powershell, jobs, start-job

I have a function `mainFunction` that gets 2 parameters - `$name` will be just a regular string, and `$moveFunction` will be some function.

I want to start a job of a ScriptBlock (`$SB`) that will invoke `$moveFunction` with `$name` as his argument.

```
function foo($a){
    Write-Output "In function foo with the argument => $a"
}

$SB = { 
        param($C, $fooFunction)
        $fooFunction.Invoke($C)
     } 

function mainFunction($name, $moveFunction){
    Start-Job  -Name "currentJob" -ArgumentList $name, ${Function:$moveFunction} -ScriptBlock $SB

}


$j1 = mainFunction -name "output!" -moveFunction $Function:foo
```

I checked that `$moveFunction` exists in `mainFunction` already (`$moveFunction.invoke(5)` at `mainFunction`)

I can't find the problem in passing the function as argument in the start-job.

and from `Get-Job -Name "CurrentJob" | Receive-Job` I get:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Any help would be appreciated.

edit:
The problem is most likely the way I pass the function as an argument (`${Function:$moveFunction}`

Comment: I did a little poking around and it looks like someone already answered this type of question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11844992/5339918). Essentially, Args for Jobs and Remote commands are Serialized. ScriptBlock comes out the other end as a String. Just call `$func = [ScriptBlock]::Create($func)` to convert that string back into a SB proper and invoke as per normal.

Comment: @RiverHeart Eventually your comment really helped me. Add your answer I'll approve it =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a rehash of my previous comment plus code example. Similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11844992/5339918). Essentially, arguments passed to Jobs and Remote commands are serialized. During the de-serialization process, functions and script blocks come out as strings instead of their original type. Fortunately it's a simple process to transform these into invokable scriptblocks using `[ScriptBlock]::Create("string")`.

```
function foo {
    write-host "foo"
}

function bar {
    # This argument comes in as a string
    param($func)
    write-host "bar"

    # Create scriptblock from string
    $func = [ScriptBlock]::Create($func)
    $func.invoke()
}

Start-Job -ArgumentList $Function:Foo -ScriptBlock $Function:Bar

Get-Job | Wait-job
Get-Job | Receive-job
```

Answer (score 1):

You passing the same function and invoking it. You can directly use the function in the job.

```
Start-Job  -Name "currentJob" -ArgumentList $name - ScriptBlock ${function:foo}
```

Comment: I'll look at your answer at depth tomorrow, but from a fast run it doesn't go. The call is still `$j1 = mainFunction -name "output!" -moveFunction $Function:foo` ?

Comment: You can even `Start-Job  -Name "currentJob" -ArgumentList $name, $Function:foo - ScriptBlock $SB`

Comment: Did nobody read my comment from above? :(
This doesn't work because the script block is serialized and comes out as a string when passed to the job. You need to take that string and generate a new scriptblock.

Comment: yup, It will de-serialize,  I didn't notice your comment.

Comment: @sheldonzyyou can directly call the function in the job.