# Running multiple different ScriptBlocks with RSJobs

Tags: powershell, jobs, scriptblock, poshrsjob

I have multiple different scriptblocks that I want to run with `Start-RSJob` from the [PoshRSJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob) module.

I have the following code:

```
$SB1 = {Write-Output "Hello from 1"}
$SB2 = {Write-Output "Hello from 2"}
$SB3 = {Write-Output "Hello from 3"}
$SB4 = {Write-Output "Hello from 4"}

$SBs = @($SB1, $SB2, $SB3, $SB4)

$SBs | Start-RSJob -ScriptBlock {
    $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | ForEach {
        . $_.Value
    }
}

Get-RSJob | Wait-RSJob
```

which works, but I'm getting sometimes (sometimes no errors, sometimes with erros) errors inside the jobs like for the job that executed `$SB3`:

```
Stack empty.
Hello from 3
```

And from the job that executed `$SB4`:

```
Stack empty.
Hello from 4
```

And from the other two jobs I got the expected output:

```
Hello from 1
Hello from 2
```

I'm not using the `ForEach` to start new jobs because that is what the creator said:

> Notice that I do not use ForEach when using Start-RSJob. This takes
>   input directly from the pipeline to work properly and fully utilize
>   the throttling capabilities.

Edit:

So the following works:

```
$SB1 = {Write-Output "Hello from 1"}
$SB2 = {Write-Output "Hello from 2"}
$SB3 = {Write-Output "Hello from 3"}
$SB4 = {Write-Output "Hello from 4"}

$SBs = @($SB1, $SB2, $SB3, $SB4)

Get-RSJob | Remove-RSJob

$SBs |Start-RSJob -ScriptBlock {
    $PSBoundParameters.GetEnumerator() | ForEach {
        $SB_run = [ScriptBlock]::Create($_.Value)
        $SB_run.Invoke()
    }
}

Get-RSJob | Wait-RSJob | Receive-RSJob
```

But I have no idea why the previous one didn't.

Comment: You might get some clue from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53470066/powershell-start-job-invoke-function-argument-with-parameter/53474503#53474503

Answer (score 0):

from what i can tell, you need to enclose the call to the RSJob cmdlet in a `ForEach-Object` call. it seems that `Start-RSJob` does not ***directly*** accept a scriptblock via the pipeline. the `Start-Job` cmdlet has that limitation.